# Docusign integrator key and username relationship

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using a [legacy service integration](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/legacy_auth.html) with DocuSign (through custom X-DocuSign-Authentication header attribute) and I'm a bit confused with the relationship between username and Integrator-Key.

For example, for test purposes I've used the following scenario:

1. I've send a request to sign a document and obtained the **envelopeId** using Integrator-Key-**1**
2. After I'm sending a request to get the recipient view url (for embedded signing) using the same credentials and provided **envelopeId**, but **another** Integrator-Key-**2**

I was expecting that the request should fail, but it works fine and the document is displayed for signature. 
I'm getting the same result even in case the provided integrator key belongs to different user.

So, I'm really confused what the integrator-key is used for.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integrator key identifies the ***integration***. Once approved for use within a specific DocuSign environment (e.g., demo, prod), an integrator key can be used to issue API requests for data affiliated with any Account and/or User within that environment (provided, of course, that each API request includes proper info to authenticate the User who's making the API request).

So, for example, if you're an ISV who's building an integration that will be used by multiple customers across multiple DocuSign Accounts, you can use the same integrator key for all API calls that your integration issues, regardless of the Account and/or User affiliated with any particular request.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any documentation covering this you could link to here? I want to try using a single Integration Key with multiple accounts in a sandbox environment, but so far it seems the sandbox is limited to a single account. So I am concerned I won't be able to test/confirm this behaviour before deploying to the live environment.

Comment: I'm not sure about official documentation -- but this video posted to the DocuSign blog by one of their Sr. Developer Advocates: https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-dev-w-ds-integration-keys. This video contains info that aligns with my answer above - i.e., "An integration key represents an application,..." and "The application (with its IK) can be used by anyone on any account that includes API support."

Answer (score 1):

Integrator key (also known as a client id) is a unique identifier that authenticates your account with the DocuSign API. If you have two Integrator Keys for the same environment then you will be able to call DS APIs with any Integrator Key. But Integrator Key has more value for DocuSign, for instance if you have created an application with DS APIs with IK 1 and you reviewed this IK to be used in the PROD environment. After you have passed the review process, IK will be promoted to PROD environment enabling you to call DS APIs in Live/Prod environment within API rules and limits. Now in future you did any code changes on your end and your newly deployed code was not developed as per DS API Rules and Limits then DS can blacklist your IK to not to be used in PROD, which will impact your application to be stopped in the PROD directly.